LvCharts RowSeries X-axis ticks not displaying correctly
When displaying values within 10, the X-axis ticks display correctly, but when the values exceed 10, the X-axis only shows the first tick at 0. I tried setting MinValue and MaxValue on the X-axis, but it didn’t fix the issue. How can I solve this?
Here is the XAML code:
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <lvc:CartesianChart>
            <!--X-->
            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                <lvc:Axis MinValue="0" MaxValue="100" ShowLabels="True" Labels="0,10,20,30,40,50">
                    <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                        <lvc:Separator Stroke="Red" StrokeDashArray="10"/>
                    </lvc:Axis.Separator>
                </lvc:Axis>
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <!--Y-->
            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                <lvc:Axis MinValue="0" MaxValue="5" ShowLabels="True" Labels="01,2,3,4,5">
                    <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                        <lvc:Separator Stroke="Green" StrokeDashArray="10"/>
                    </lvc:Axis.Separator>
                </lvc:Axis>
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <!--values-->
            <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
                <lvc:RowSeries DataLabels="True" LabelsPosition="Parallel" Values="20,30,10,50,40" Fill="Orange"/>
            </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
            
        </lvc:CartesianChart>
    </Grid>

Additional Context:

I have tried removing the Labels property to see if it automatically fixes the issue, but it didn't help.
I have also tried adjusting the MaxValue to a larger number, but the problem persists.

How can I resolve this so that all X-axis ticks display correctly regardless of the values?
